# Does openconnect have native support for Pulse Secure?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openconnect

Since they rolled out Pulse Secure in place of Network Connect, I have been attempting to connect to my company's vpn using openconnect.

I am seemingly able to run openconnect without errors, do the the 2-factor auth, etc. but am subsequently unable to access apis that live behind the firewall.

Does anybody know if openconnect has native support for Pulse Secure now, or is it still experimental?

I happen to be working on Ubuntu 16.04 if that is at all relevant.

```
> sudo openconnect --juniper --user=example remote.example.com
WARNING: Juniper Network Connect support is experimental.
It will probably be superseded by Junos Pulse support.
GET https://remote.example.com/
Connected to 123.45.67.89:443
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found
GET https://remote.example.com/example/welcome.cgi
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
frmLogin
realm [Example 1|Example 2]:Example 1
frmLogin
password:
POST https://remote.example.com/example/login.cgi
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved
GET https://remote.example.com/example/welcome.cgi?p=more-cred&id=state_1234567890
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
frmLogin
user#2:example
password#2:
POST https://remote.example.com/example/login.cgi
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 302 Moved
GET https://remote.example.com/example/starter0.cgi?check=yes
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
SSL negotiation with remote.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on remote.example.com
Connected as 10.10.10.10, using SSL
```